# How to Convert datatype from char to datetime

Tags: sql

When i query like this:

```
select date_in from tb_user
where year(convert(datetime,date_in,103))= '2015'
```

Error message pop out:

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Datatype is char. How can I convert to datetime?

Comment: Can you show some sample data for `data_in` please?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?